# Black dots on betta fins

Tags: fish, betta

I have a giant veil tailed betta. Two days ago I moved him from a 2.5 gallon tank (filtered and heated) to a 10 gallon tank with a divider. One side of the divider has him and there is another male betta in the other side. At first they noticed each other and were mad but they don’t seem to care anymore. Both very active. In my giant betta, he has developed little black dots all over his fins since he was moved into this new tank. I read something that it is rare but when you move a fish into a darker environment then they could develop these spots. Could this be it? I would really appreciate any help. This new tank is filtered and heated. Each fish has 5 gallons.[image: black dots shown on fins][image]

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge this is normal. This is a common occurrence in blue betta or blue fish in general. It is just the fish maturing or like you said just a change in the environment. As long as he is acting normal, I wouldn't worry. The only thing I am unsure on is the very end of the tail from the first picture it looks like tail rot but the second it doesn't; regardless the black spots are normal and there is nothing to worry about.